# Get directory, sub directory and files from server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, stream

I'm building a .NET app, and I recently added a way to upload pictures on a server (with a WebService). My app retrieves the pictures as FileStreams, pass them to a WebService's method, which then copies "locally" (on the server) the pictures :

```
public void SendPhotos(Stream stream)
    {
        string folder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defaultfolderpath"];
        if (!Directory.Exists(folder + "Trucs et Astuces"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folder + "Trucs et Astuces");
        if (!Directory.Exists(folder + "Trucs et Astuces\\" + refHD))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folder + "Trucs et Astuces\\" + refHD);

        string filename = folder + @"Trucs et Astuces\" + refHD + Guid.NewGuid();
        FileStream f = File.Create(filename);
        stream.CopyTo(f);
        f.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }
```

I would like to do the same in the opposite way, retrieves the pictures from the server and copy them locally on my computer. Do you have any idea to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Well the path is in `filename` so read from that? (Unrelated but Path.Combine() is your friend for path building)

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the web service, then you can prefix/suffix your upload file names with any identification string (like timestamp or anyother you are familier with) and retrieve the files accordingly and send them as download files.

Answer (score 0):

This following function will read an image using string as a path and returns a stream which can be turned into StreamContent when returning from a API.

```
    private StreamContent ReadImageAsStream(string imagePath)
    {
        // Code here to get image based on above parameter

        //TODO remove url
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imagePath))
        {
            return Image.FromFile(@"\\Content\Images\no_image_available.png").ToStream(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }

        // Read and return image as stream
        return Image.FromFile(imagePath).ToStream(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

and the controller if using Web API

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetImageByObjectId(string imagePath)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ReadImageAsStream(imagePath));
    }
```

Of course you are better off identifying the image in some other way, other than supplying the path as a parameter.